# Добавление записи в связанные таблицы MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Дана База данных, состоящая из двух несвязанных таблиц "users" и "textlog".
В users добавляются пользователи, а в textlog записи, которые они делают.
Все работает корректно.
Есть задача - получать в таблице textlog пользователя, добавившего запись.
Для этого в таблице textlog создается поле user_id, которое связывается с полем id таблицы users.

И всё перестает работать. Данные из поля ввода в таблицу textlog не попадают.

Предполагаю ошибку запроса, но как ее подправить решить не могу.

Как решить эту проблему?

Вот функция добавления в БД на php:

```
function textlog($connect, $chat_id, $text) {

    if ($chat_id = '')
        return false;
    $t = "INSERT INTO textlog (chat_id, phone) VALUES ('%s', '%s')";
    $query = sprintf($t, mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $chat_id),
//            mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text));
        mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, substr($text, 1)));
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

    if (!$result)
        die(mysqli_error($connect));
    return true;

}
```

Comment: а где  в запросе user_id?

Comment: Предполагается, что user_id - связываемое поле, куда значения попадают из поля id таблицы users.

Comment: Как же оно попадёт туда? Вот кто-то сделал запись. Как база поймёт кто это был? В таблице пользователей например 1000 сток. Какую связывать? Возможно вы неправильно поняли идею внешних ключей, но они не заполняют поля автоматически.

Comment: Ясно, как тогда добавить user_id? Не могу понять, я пробовал добавлять $t = "INSERT INTO textlog (chat_id, phone, USER_ID) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')"; вот так. Все равно не работает.

Comment: покажите структуру таблиц (хотя бы show create table textlog)

Comment: textlog: id int(11), chat_id int(111), phone varchar(11), date datetime, user_id int(11).  users: id int(11), username varchar(50), chat_id int(111), name varchar(50), date datetime

Comment: Артем, структура подразумевает не только тип поля, но и такие атрибуты как  null | not null, default. А так же информацию по ключам (в том числе внешним, с которыми у вас и возникла проблема). `show create table` показывает всю эту информацию, её можно скопировать в вопрос, оформив как код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо добавить значение для user_id.

Если вы ещё плохо знаете SQL, то проверяйте свои запросы через клиент базы данных (если умеете через консольный, через IDE или [adminer](https://www.adminer.org/), [phpmyadmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/)). Подставьте в запрос подходящие данные и выполните его без вашего php-кода. Если запрос завершился без ошибок, то можете добавить его в свой код, подставив в него переменные (например через
sprintf, как вы это делаете). Если возникнет ошибка, то переведите её и постарайтесь понять в чём проблема.

```sql
insert into `textlog` (
    `chat_id`,
    `phone`,
    `user_id`
) values (
    123,
    '1234567890',
    456
)
```

Comment: Егор, Вам спасибо! Вопрос решил вопрос. Присвоил для user_id, id из таблицы users. И написал параметризованный запрос к БД. Всё заработало.